# Smooth transitions on grid in Vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm attempting to show/hide elements of a grid using vuetify, but can't seem to get them to play well with transitions.  In the codepen below, I'm trying to hide and show a column smoothly and have the blue section slide in behind.  Instead, the red transitions, then the blue snaps in when the element is removed.

```
      <v-layout row>
        <transition name="slide-x-transition">
        <v-flex v-if="showRed" xs4 style="background-color:red">
        </v-flex>
        </transition>
        <v-flex style="background-color:blue"> <!--Doesn't smoothly fill in-->
          <v-btn @click="showRed = !showRed">HIDE/SHOW</v-btn>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
```

Likewise, with the white/green, I'm wanting the flex boxes to transition smoothly, but instead I get smooth animation for the content and the boxes snap once it's finished.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YRVoqj

Comment: where's the CSS rules?

Comment: I'm not using any custom CSS.  I'm only using what comes pre-defined with vuetify.

Comment: I've not had any luck with tables having transitions either. [This says they decided not to implement group ones](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/468) so maybe that's why.